# Site not working Error if the function is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, error-handling

I have a function which **checks and authenticates** the `User` and on that basis the data is displayed to the respective User. And the function name is `Get_AuthenticateUser_Ums(strUserName);`

I call this function on `Page_load`. This function contains a `web service`. Now what I want is whenever the service is not working or has some issue, I want that the site should not be displayed to the user and message should prompt as `The service is down, so couldnt load the site.`

Below is my code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Get_AuthenticateUser_Ums(strUserName); }
```

And function

```
private void Get_AuthenticateUser_Ums(string strUserName)
    {
        try
        {
            strReturnMessage = string.Empty;

            Boolean bolReturn = ObjUMS.AuthenticateApplicationAccess(strUserName, strAppUrl, out strReturnMessage);

            if (bolReturn)
            {
                DataSet dsUserGroups = new DataSet();
                dsUserGroups = ObjUMS.GetUserAppDetailsbyUserNameApplicationUrl(strUserName, strAppUrl, out strReturnMessage);

                if (dsUserGroups.Tables[1] != null && dsUserGroups.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string strSubGroupName = dsUserGroups.Tables[1].Rows[0]["SUBGROUP_NAME"].ToString();

                    if (strSubGroupName == "UBR Requester")
                    {
                        if (dsUserGroups.Tables[2] != null && dsUserGroups.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string[] allStates = dsUserGroups.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("BOUNDARY_VALUE")).ToArray();
                            ViewState["States"] = string.Join(",", allStates);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorize.aspx", false);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorize.aspx", false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorize.aspx", false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working from this part? what response you are getting from this?

Comment: @sangramparmar: `ObjUMS.AuthenticateApplicationAccess(strUserName, strAppUrl, out strReturnMessage);` if there will be error then message will be given other wise blank

Comment: @VVVV  message will be given means?

Comment: @Webruster: I mean if that web service is not working or stopped then message should prompt as `Site is down due to some technical issues`. something like that

Comment: @VVVV is it navigating to the `NotAuthorize` page?

Comment: @Webruster: it is navigating whenever an unauthorized user is trying to view the site but my issue is related to web service.

Comment: @VVVV  i'm assuming this is ur service method `ObjUMS.GetUserAppDetailsbyUserNameApplicationUrl` , so when ever a service is down what is the value you are getting in `boolreturn` ?

Comment: @Webruster: whenever it is down it will go into the catch part with some message in `strReturnMessage` which is my third parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153835/discussion-between-webruster-and-vvvv).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `Method` to check connection using the `url to svc` , and which returns a `boolean` based on that you can able to see whether the Service is up or not

```
public bool checkConnection(){ 
var url = "http://nvmbd1bkh150v02/UMSService/UserProvider.svc"; 
bool tosend = false; 
try 
{ 
var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 

var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse(); 

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{ 
tosend = true ; 
// it's at least in some way responsive 
// but may be internally broken 
// as you could find out if you called one of the methods for real 
Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} Available", url)); 
} 
else 
{ 
tosend = false; 
// well, at least it returned... 
Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} Returned, but with status: {1}", 
url, response.StatusDescription)); 
} 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
// not available at all, for some reason 
Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} unavailable: {1}", url, ex.Message)); 
} 

return tosend; 
}
```